# Invalid Time String Error when trying to change type of data from string to time

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting, data-analysis

I am very new to data analytics and I need some help troubleshooting a SQL error I got. So, I have a column in this table which transferred over from Excel to SQL as a string type rather than a time piece of data. I want to make it into a time type so i can further analyze it.

So, I did the attached query to try and change the type of data using the CAST function. [image: Image from BigQuery]. However, it could not complete the query thanks to an outlier in the data set I have yet to clean the data and this was one of my first steps to so, but how do I remove this particular row that contains the invalid time string so the query can actually work? Or is there a better way to convert this entire column from text string to time?

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: A time is what you get on a clock. There is no 330 o'clock, and it wouldn't make sense for a `ride_length` anyway (a ride length of `half past two in the afternoon` would be gibberish). You don't have a time, you have a duration / interval, so try casting it to `INTERVAL` instead of `TIME`. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#cast_as_interval (Not that a ride length of 330 hours makes much sense either, but you can filter that with a where clause.)

Comment: Thanks for the help MatBailie but now I got a new issue. When I CAST ride_length as an INTERVAL somewhere in my csv files there has to be an issue because now Im getting that there is an invalid INTERVAL value. And the interval value is a bunch of #######. So, I think what I need to do is to delete problematic rows such as the 330 hour error and this new ### one. How do I go about deleting a row from a table that is giving me problems?

Answer (score -1):

BigQuery Time types adjust values outside the 24 hour boundary - `00:00:00` to `24:00:00`; for example, if you subtract an hour from `00:30:00`, the returned value is `23:30:00`.

Based on your screenshot it looks like you are storing a duration?  So 330 hours, 25 minutes and 55 seconds?

You would probably be best using timestamp, converting the hours to days and adding the remainder to your minutes and seconds.

You can then cast the resulting string to timestamp.

**Edit**

A much simpler solution is just `cast('330:25:55' as interval)` - thanks to @MatBailie

[image]

Comment: Bigquery supports interval types, so why use dates, times, timestamps at all? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#cast_as_interval

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie, I wasn't aware that `interval` had been added to the possible column types. Have edited my answer